# C# and inheritance chain of multiple types using generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, clr

I have this setup, and it didn't work as I expected. It seems to me that a generic T in a base class is not the same as the generic T in its sub-class.

```
namespace StackOverflowQuestion
{
    public class Poco1
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Poco2 : Poco1
    {
        public string ExtraData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Poco3 : Poco2
    {
        public string EvenMoreData { get; set; }
    }


    public class Base<T> where T: Poco1
    {
        public virtual void Method(T parameter)
        {
            // Do something even more general with Data...
            parameter.Data = "Test";
        }
    }

    public class FirstLevel<T> : Base<Poco2> where T:Poco2
    {
        public override void Method(Poco2 parameter)
        {
            // Do something general with ExtraData...
            base.Method(parameter);
        }
    }

    public class SecondLevel<T> : FirstLevel<Poco3> where T: Poco3
    {
        public override void Method(Poco2 parameter)  // <-- Why not Poco3?
        {
            // Do something with EvenMoreData...
            base.Method(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

What I actually expected was that the `Method` override in type `SecondLevel<T>` should say `Poco3` and not `Poco2`. Especially as I put a constraint on T to be of type `Poco3`.

Is it possible to achieve this in another way? It seems to me that the generic T can't be *"overridden"* the way I wanted. I suspect T in `Base<T>` is not the same as T in `FirstLevel<T>` and that T in `FirstLevel<T>` is not the same as T in `SecondLevel<T>`?

If `SecondLevel<T>` inherits from `Base<T>` then I get `Poco3` in the `Method` override, but not when I inherit from `FirstLevel<T>`.

I can live with this issue, but then I need to cast the poco parameter type in Level-type sub-classes (from level 2 and up). In my opinion, that should be unnecessary as long as I specify the constraint. But, of course, there might be a good reason for this behavior that I don't see at the moment.

Comment: use this signature for all the inheriting types: public override void Method(T parameter)

Comment: @AndyJ You're my hero! Of course, why didn't I see this? If you paste my code and replace every Poco reference (except in the contraints) with T, I'll mark it as an answer immediately :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than specifying the POCO type in each overridden method signature you can instead use the T type parameter.

T is already constrained to the POCO type you want so it should behave exactly as you want.

Oh, and I'd do the same with the type you're passing to the base class as well.

e.g.

```
public class FirstLevel<T> : Base<T> where T:Poco2
{
    public override void Method(T parameter)
    {
        // Do something general with ExtraData...
        base.Method(parameter);
    }
}

public class SecondLevel<T> : FirstLevel<T> where T: Poco3
{
    public override void Method(T parameter)
    {
        // Do something with EvenMoreData...
        base.Method(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Its my first ever attempt to inherit types with generic arguments at more than two levels. Its so obvious when I saw your answer.

Comment: No probs. I just edited the answer to also suggesting using the type parameter T for passing to the base class as well. Then it's T's all the way down heh.

Comment: Have been fighting with this issue the whole day. Now I've learned something essential new today. Perfect!